# How to remove notification icon from the status bar and notification count badge from app launcher icon on app open?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification, flutter-notification

I am using the firebase with my flutter application. The application is built for both iOS & Android platforms. Upon receiving the notification, if I click on the notification, the notification icon from the status bar removes including the notification count badge from the app launcher icon.

But, if I tap on the launcher icon instead of the notification, the notification icon in the status bar remains including the notification count badge in the app launcher icon.

As per the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_badger), to solve the issue, this is what I have done so far:

```
import ...
import 'package:flutter_app_badger/flutter_app_badger.dart';
import ...

removeTheNotifications() async {
    if(await FlutterAppBadger.isAppBadgeSupported()){
      FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(0);
      FlutterAppBadger.removeBadge();
    }
}
```

And calling this method in the build function of the flutter screen:

```
removeTheNotifications();
```

But it makes no difference and does not work. Thanks